# Firestore Database Console loading problem

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I am trying to open the Cloud Firestore from Firebase Console. It keeps loading and loading, without ever showing the available data. The database itself works fine, since I have successfully tried posting something. So I guess the UI of the Firebase Console is to blame. Has anyone encountered this issue before, and if yes, is there anything I can do to fix it?

[image: Cloud Firestore loading]

Update: The problem persists on Chrome and Microsoft Edge, but disappears when opening the Firebase Console with Firefox.

Comment: I just quickly tested the console for some of my projects and Firestore data loads without problems there. You might want to try disabling all extensions and/or run in incognito mode to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Just tried opening the Cloud Firestore from Firebase Console using the InPrivate mode of Microsoft Edge and using the Incognito Mode of Chrome. The problem persists in both cases. In Firefox everything still works as it is supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this problem few weeks ago and first I thought it was a chrome update bug, or cache related problem since Firebase cloud service was online all the time. And then just today, I've decided to clean up unused chrome extensions out of nowhere and problem was gone.

**Solution**

- Delete unused chrome extensions

For me, I've deleted Autoview, some vpn extension and cors extensions. Not sure which one exactly caused the problem but I think this is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The error is related to usage limitation on free plan. Check Data usage to verify it. If you exceed daily usage limit, it will be blocked until next day (pacific time). And it error will resolve automatically.

You can check your plan usage in firebase console here:
[image: Cloud Firestore Usage]

Answer (score 0):

I also tried opening three projects in Firestore and didn't encounter the issue you mentioned. I tried Chrome Version 93.

By looking at the [status dashboard](https://status.firebase.google.com/), all Firebase services are up and running at this time.

If you still experience this issue, I suggest testing on a different device, deleting cache/cookies, updating your browsers. If it's still the same, contacting the [GCP Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub/).

Comment: any solution? this is happening right now for me

Comment: me too, i delete browser history, open in new profile chrome. but still got nothing. any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

for me, after deleted browser history, open url in new profile chrome. but still not working.
i try to active ipv6 for network adapter and its working fine.